# Phpmailer AddBcc not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am using phpmailer to sent email, and it works the recipients receive the mail except the bcc and cc details is not showing the mail. Someone can suggest a solution to this
.
the code is

```
require_once("PHPMailer_v5.1/class.phpmailer.php");
require_once("PHPMailer_v5.1/language/phpmailer.lang-en.php");              
$mailer = new PHPMailer();
$mailer->IsSMTP();              
$mailer->SMTPAuth = true;                   
$mailer->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mailer->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mailer->Port = 587;                
$mailer->Username = "myuserid";
$mailer->Password = "mypassword";
$mailer->FromName = $fromname;
$mailer->From = "myuserid";             
$mailer->AddAddress("to@gmail.com",$toname);                
$mailer->Subject = $subject;                
$mailer->Body =$content;                
$mailer->AddCC("something@gmail.com", "bla");               
$mailer->AddBCC("foo@gmail.com", "test");
if(!$mailer->Send())
{
echo "Message was not sent";
}
else
echo "mail sent";
```

Comment: isn't AddBCC? also - you're not clear: do the BCC recipients receive the email?

Comment: AddBCC still not working, bcc recipients will also receive the mail

Answer (score 40):

Use as

```
$mailer->AddBCC("foo@gmail.com", "test");
$mailer->AddCC("something@gmail.com", "bla");
```

Comment: still not working... the mail recieves, but the bcc recipient cant view the bcc details

Answer (score 18):

You never see BCC details. That's what they are BCC details for. Even the recipient of a BCC will not see his own name with the recipients.

PS: You noticed you wrote `addBCC` instead of `AddBCC` (capital `A`)?

Comment: I think the bcc recipient can view all the recipient details, but here the bcc recipient can't view the bcc details only 'to details' can view

Comment: That is always so. BCC details are always hidden, also when you are yourself the BCC recipient. Just send a mail from your favorite client and you'll see.

Comment: class methods are case insensitive.  Capital A makes no difference.

Answer (score 13):

From the phpMailer function reference:

> Adds a "Bcc" address. Note: this function works with the SMTP mailer on win32, not with the "mail" mailer.

This might be causing your issue.

Answer (score 9):

[PHPMailer not sending CC or BCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14691373/phpmailer-not-sending-cc-or-bcc?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Old question, but I ended up here looking for an answer. Just learned elsewhere that those functions AddCC and AddBCC only work with win32 SMTP

Try using:

$mail->addCustomHeader("BCC: mybccaddress@mydomain.com"); 
See http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=methods

Hope this helps someone, cheers!

Comment: Alternative ways to write this are `$mail->addCustomHeader('BCC', 'mybccaddress@mydomain.com');` and `$emails = array('address1@mydomain.com', 'address2@mydomain.com'); $mail->addCustomHeader('BCC', implode(',', $emails));`.

Answer (score 6):

It´s addBCC

```
$email->addBCC('my@email.com', 'My Name');
```

See PHPMailer.php (current version 6.0.5) on line 934 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L934):

```
/**
 * Add a "BCC" address.
 *
 * @param string $address The email address to send to
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return bool true on success, false if address already used or invalid in some way
 */
public function addBCC($address, $name = '')
{
    return $this->addOrEnqueueAnAddress('bcc', $address, $name);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

the bcc will never show; only TO and CC

BCC=Blind Carbon Copy

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example from the newest release, and on Office 365, I use it to send email from shared folders...

```
<?
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    require_once('./phpmailer/Exception.php');
    require_once('./phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');
    require_once('./phpmailer/SMTP.php');
    //*  Working Example As Of 09/21/2019  - Sends From Shared Mailbox With Mailbox Member
    function SendO365EmailTLS($options)
    {
        $from =          isset($options['from'])          ? $options['from']          : false;
        $recipients =    isset($options['recipients'])    ? $options['recipients']    : false;
        $ccRecipeints =  isset($options['ccrecipients'])  ? $options['ccrecipients']  : [];
        $bccRecipients = isset($options['bccrecipients']) ? $options['bccrecipients'] : [];
        $attachments =   isset($options['attachments'])   ? $options['attachments']   : [];
        $credentials =   isset($options['credentials'])   ? $options['credentials']   : false;
        $subject =       isset($options['subject'])       ? $options['subject']       : '';
        $body =          isset($options['body'])          ? $options['body']          : '';
        if(!$from)        throw new Exception('Cannot send email with blank \'from\' field');
        if(!$recipients)  throw new Exception('Cannot send email, no recipients specified!');
        if(!$credentials) throw new Exception('Cannot send email, credentials not provided!');
        $mail = new PHPMailer;
        foreach($recipients as $recipient)       $mail->addAddress(   $recipient[   'email'],   $recipient['name']);
        foreach($ccRecipeints as $ccRecipient)   $mail->addCC(        $ccRecipient[ 'email'], $ccRecipient['name']);
        foreach($bccRecipients as $bccRecipient) $mail->addBCC(       $bccRecipient['email'],$bccRecipient['name']);
        foreach($attachments as $attachment)     $mail->addAttachment($attachment[  'path' ],  $attachment['name']);
        $mail->setFrom($from['email'], $from['name']);
        $mail->Username = $credentials['username'];
        $mail->Password = $credentials['password'];
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        $mail->Body    = $body;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $success = $mail->send();
        return $success;
    }
//  $options = ['from'=>          ['email'=>'', 'name'=>''],
//              'recipients'=>   [['email'=>'', 'name'=>'']],
//              'ccrecipients'=> [['email'=>'', 'name'=>'']],
//              'bccrecipients'=>[['email'=>'', 'name'=>'']],
//              'attachments'=>  [['path'=>'./attachments/file1.jpg','name'=>'1.jpg'],
//                                ['path'=>'./attachments/file2.jpg','name'=>'2.jpg'],
//                                ['path'=>'./attachments/file3.jpg','name'=>'3.jpg']],
//              'credentials'=>   ['username'=>'','password'=>''],
//              'subject'=>        'Email Subject Line',
//              'body'=>           '<h1>Email Body</h1><p>HTML!!!</p>'];
//  $success = SendO365EmailTLS($options);
//  echo $success ? 'Email Sent':'Email Not Sent';
//  die();
```

Answer (score 0):

$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');//Carbon copy
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');//Blind Carbon copy

Please Read This
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score -15):

To operate the clausla BCC AddCC MUST precede as well nuloy hidden email will arrive to your recipient would otherwise happen nuna
Example:

```
$ mail-> AddCC ("");
$ mail-> AddBCC ("mail @ domain")
```

Comment: This answer needs major rewording, and possibly formatting. It's really unclear what you mean. "nuloy"? Also, please use the code formatting tools provided.

Comment: this answer is more confusing than it is helpful.

Comment: Mailer Error: Invalid address: (cc)